# perl match multiple words with space

Tags: regex, perl

i am trying to find all matching words which start with the following and ignore them

```
Delta Asset Management
Viger
Double binding
Base camp lift
```

i tried it via this regex but  not getting right result.

```
if ($row =~ m/^(Delta Asset Management|Viger|Double binding|Base camp lift)/){ return undef; }
```

Comment: That code works fine on my end. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Examples, please. What does your data look like?

Comment: I feel like there's a communication gap in this post.  It could just be you used "words" instead of "lines", but it also could be you're using words in a different way than I'm used to.  Like if you were trying to match all of the terms that started with those 1-3 words, and the terms don't necessarily start a line, then the answer you received might not be so horribly wrong.  The missing examples of what should and should not be matched that currently isn't or is being matched would do nicely to clarify this.

Answer (score -4):

change the regex to remove the `^` and add `/g` (global) like:

```
/(Delta Asset Management|Viger|Double binding|Base camp lift)/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A6B8uf/1)

or, if you need to keep the `^`, add `/m` (multiline option) like:

```
/^(Delta Asset Management|Viger|Double binding|Base camp lift)/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A6B8uf/2)

Comment: Using `/g` in a boolean check tends to be a bug.

Comment: @melpomene: I'd be inclined to say that it's *always* a bug. Perhaps `if ( s///g )` has a purpose, but not the `if ( m//g )` that we have here.

Comment: @Borodin I've used `if ( m//g )` in parsers, but yeah, not in this context.

Comment: @melpomene: Okay, I wonder what your reason was for that choice? The only other thing I can think of is that you may achieve a side-effect using `(?{ ... })` etc. that you want applied at every match, but ultimately extract a boolean value to say whether *any* matches were found.

Comment: @Borodin ... OK, that comment makes no sense to me. Are you sure you know what `/g` does in scalar context?